# Android - Change the scrollbar track drawable at runtime and force the scrollbar to update

Tags: android, view, colors, runtime, scrollbar

I'm using the *android:scrollbarTrackVertical* attribute of a View to change the background color of the vertical scroll bar track:

```
android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_track"
```

The "scrollbar_vertical_track" drawable is defined as:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00FF00" />
</shape>
```

At runtime, I change the color of the drawable using:

```
    GradientDrawable d = (GradientDrawable)(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.scrollbar_vertical_track));
    d.setColor(color);
```

How can I force the View (I'm using a WebView) to update the color of the scrollbar track? It seems it only works after I restart the activity. I've tried different methods (*invalidate*, etc. - none works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the function [protected void initializeScrollbars(TypedArray a)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#initializeScrollbars%28android.content.res.TypedArray%29) in View. I'd suggest that you try to extend WebView and expose a wrapper to this function. Thus you'll be able to arbitrary call it. Might be worth to check this approach.